# Using cocoapods without use_frameworks! in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

According to [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7076593-cocoapods-tutorial-for-swift-getting-started) tutorial, we should add `use_frameworks!` to `Podfile` in Swift project. But how to use third-party code in `.m` in the same project?

One possible way is,

- Do NOT add `use_frameworks!` to `Podfile`
- Import header in `...-Bridging-Header.h`
- Then, I can use third-party code in both .swift and .m file

But when I try to import header in `...-Bridging-Header.h`, it just throw `*.h file not found` error, how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Past

Up to CocoaPods 1.4.x (included), it was NOT possible to use CocoaPods with Swift code without `use_frameworks!`.

#### Present: 1.x.x and above

Nowadays, with CocoaPods 1.x.x (I verified it with 1.4.0), it's common to use `use_frameworks!` for both Swift and ObjC projects: it allows for a mix of the two languages in any way you want without issues:

- You'll be able to use a Swift dependency in an Objective-C project.
- You'll be able to use an Objective-C dependency in a Swift project.

#### Present: 1.5.x and above

Nowadays, CocoaPods 1.5.0 [supports integrating swift pods as static libraries](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6899). Try it (`sudo gem install cocoapods`) and enjoy removing `use_frameworks!` from your Podfile.

---

Note that for iOS:

- Apple requires Xcode 10.1 minimum, which is only well supported [starting CocoaPods 1.6.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/8727), so don't bother using older versions of CocoaPods.
- Apple will require Xcode 11 minimum in April 2020, for which I would only use CocoaPods 1.7.5 or newer, together with xcodeproj 1.13.0 or newer.

Comment: For Xcode 11 compatibility, I would only use CocoaPods 1.7.5 or newer.